# Prove that $\min_{\mu}\sum_{i=1}^n|y_i-\mu|=\text{median}\{y_1,\cdots,y_n\}$

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, economics, quantile

How to prove the equation below in a simple way?
$$\min_{\mu}\sum_{i=1}^n|y_i-\mu|=\text{median}\{y_1,\cdots,y_n\}$$